# html trying to access fields before promise finishes

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise, angular5

I have a field in my TS class: `currentMonth: Month;` and `ngOnInit()` method, which make a GET request and initialize this field:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getAllMonth(this.currentYear).subscribe(data => {

  // setting current month
  this.currentMonth = data.find(function (m) {
    return m.numberInYear === currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  });
```

After getting a current month, I want to generate days for it and display some of them. I do this with following:

1) calling a method in `ngOnInit()`

```
this.generateDaysForCurrentMonth(this.currentMonth);
```

2) The method:

```
private generateDaysForCurrentMonth(mon: Month) {
let days = new Array<Day>();
 for(var i = 0; i < mon.numberOfDays; i++) {
  days[i] = new Day(i, mon.name, mon.year);
 }
this.currentMonth.days = days;
}
```

3) method, which returns `n` days:

```
private getPartOfMonth(from: number, to: number): Array<Day>{
 return this.currentMonth.days.slice(from, to);
}
```

4) displaying for example 7 days:

```
<div *ngFor="let day of getPartOfMonth(0, 7)">
    <td >{{day.numberInMonth}}</td>
</div>
```

when I go to page, I got an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'days' of undefined`

In this line:

```
return this.currentMonth.days.slice(from, to);
```

something similar happens here:

```
<div *ngFor="let m of months" >
  <button (click)="loadMonth(m.name)" mat-raised-button >{{month.name}}</button>
</div>
```

`month.name`  - displays correct, but in method it pass "undefined"

What is the problem for this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use safe navigation operator. `{{currentMonth?.name}}`. It will return null and not throw error when trying to access currentMonth properties when currentMonth is null or undefined.